# Gulp src to dest not working

Tags: gulp

I am trying to copy some files and it is not working. I look at the destination and I do not see the copied files. Maybe I am missing something

```
gulp.task('bower-copy', function() {
    gulp.src('**/*/scss', {
        base: './bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/'
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Assets/sass/boostrap'));
});
```

Am I missing something? Maybe you need a plugin to actually copy?

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline isn't quite correct...

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./Assets/sass/bootstrap'));
```

Comment: Sorry that was a misttype on my end. Still not copying

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone's still watching this, but...

```
gulp.src('**/*/scss', {
    base: './bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/'
})
```

should be

```
gulp.src('**/*.scss', {
    base: './bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/'
})
```

Note the slash is replaced by a dot. you were selecting all files under a recursive path, then any folder, then the scss-folder, while what you wanted was all scss-files.